# Update reference paths for all projects in a solution at once

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I need to add a reference path to all projects (over 35 projects) in a solution. Doing this manually would be time consuming.

Is there a way to update/add/remove reference paths for all the projects programmatically?

I found an add-in that helps in what I need but unfortunately [the add-in's download link](http://weblogs.asp.net/mnolton/archive/2006/05/25/Add-In-for-updating-all-reference-paths-in-a-solution.aspx) is broken.

Answer (score 2):

You could always open the csproj files in a text editor an perform a find/replace. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has a handy [replace in files feature](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/searching/replacing).

Comment: this option can be handy in case i want to update reference path only.  what if i want to add a reference path? adding a reference path using this way will be tricky and error prone.

Comment: I agree its not ideal, but you should be able to make it work by replacing an existing reference with the same reference plus the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Visual Studio PowerCommands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/DF3F0C30-3D37-4E06-9EF8-3BFF3508BE31) you can copy and paste references, so it won't be as tedious, at least.  It makes many other things less tedious as well.

Comment: PowerCommands cant help i need to add a reference path to a central assembly location to all projects. copying works on individual assembly references level only. thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm not suggesting "copy [a project] _as_ reference", I'm suggesting you add your central assembly reference to one project, and copy _that project's_ central assembly reference and paste it to all the others.

Answer (score 0):

*If your reference is one the NuGet packages*, you can easily use the **NuGet package manager for the solution** and select the installed package that you want to remove, check desired projects, then uninstall them.

for installation: first, select the desired package, check target projects, then click install.

its work for me as I have a solution with 35 projects.