# Adding and removing multiple references across projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, refactoring, resharper

I have a huge project with over 50 or 60 csproj files. I need to remove 6 or 7 references exiting references and add 10 or 15 new references across all these projects. Is there a  mechansim to bulk add references and remove references?

Or if there is a way to say, replace reference X with Y across all projects, that would be very helpful too. Let me add that Nuget is not an option.

Comment: I wish the Visual Studio team would create some sort of adapter to allow the current VS solution to look like a local Nuget repository, with each project in the solution looking like a Nuget package.  Then you could do this easily.

Comment: this might be helpful if the reference is a NuGet package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45898835/1014320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one's easy: just write a script that opens up all your `.proj` files, removes the lines you don't need and add the lines you do. That's the easiest way. I think there are also options for writing plug-ins for VS or ReSharper, but both of these options are overkill. Project files are just XML files (=text files) after all, and can be treated as such.

Of course, if you find this to be a recurrent action, or if there is some conditional logic that you need to adhere to, then writing a plug-in is a sensible choice.

Comment: Thanks. I can definitely write a script to do this (and have). However, I was wondering if there is a tool that already does this? I am sure several people should be facing this situation.

Comment: Nope. I certainly haven't heard about such a tool.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that too, I always thought this should be a very common usecase to manage references.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reference to multiple projects in Visual Studio by writing a script/macro using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

The method below interacts with a running copy of Visual Studio rather than manipulating the text in the project files directly, it utilises the fact you can get everything (most?) things done without a mouse and using only a keyboard. It works by sending the appropriate key presses to Visual Studio such that it finds the appropriate projects, right clicks, opens references etc.

For the script to work you need to have the **Resource View** window open with a project highlighted before executing the script. This is so that it can search for the projects by name (the solution explorer may have folders that prevent this).
You will also need to adjust the script by renaming the project window *SolutionName* and the name of the reference you wish to add *ReferenceName*.
The projects.txt is just a text file in the same directory as your AutoHotKey script with the newline separated list of projects you wish to add the reference to.

*Note: I am using Visual Studio 2008. Also, I have not used any scientific method in determining my Sleep times, they may not even be necessary. This was a tactical solution and the script can no doubt be optimised and improved.*

```html
; Prepare array from project list
ArrayCount = 0 ; Initialise array counter
Loop, Read, projects.txt   ; This loop retrieves each line from the file, one at a time.
{
ArrayCount += 1  ; Keep track of how many items are in the array.
Array%ArrayCount% := A_LoopReadLine  ; Store this line in the next array element.
}
IfWinExist SolutionName - Microsoft Visual Studio (Administrator) ; Check if VS2008 with solution is running
{
WinActivate ; Bring a window to front
Loop %ArrayCount%
{
 element := Array%A_Index% ; Grabs current project name from array
 Send % element ; types the name of the project
 Sleep 100
 Send {AppsKey}F{Tab}{Tab}{Space}
 Sleep 100
 Send ReferenceName{Enter}
 Sleep 100
 Send {Enter}
 Sleep 100
}

}
else
{
MsgBox Cannot find "SolutionName - Microsoft Visual Studio (Administrator)" window.
}
```