# Add project reference recursively in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual Studio solution with 100+ C# and 2 C++ projects. Now I want to create a new project in a new solution and reference one of the existing projects (ProjectA).

My question is: how do I add all the existing projects which are referenced by ProjectA recursively and

- automatically (it's too painful to add them one by one)
- without using NuGet to pack those projects

Comment: Duplicate, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019100/adding-and-removing-multiple-references-across-projects-in-visual-studio

Comment: I ended up writing my own VS extension to do this repetitive job for me. Sorry that I can't publish it due to company policy.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

1. Copy existing ProjectA solution and name it ProjectB
2. Add a reference to the new solution to your new project.
3. Remove all other unnecessary projects in the solution.

Comment: How do I remove all other unnecessary projects?

Comment: Right click on a project in the Project Explorer, then Remove.