# Updating Visual studio multiple projects references

Tags: visual-studio

I have a vs solution which have many projects probably in the range of 30 to 40. Of course, each project have their project references such as to oracle data access dll. My question or pain is that to do an upgrade to any of my other application, e.g. oracle db, i would have to manually change all 30 project's references.

Is there a simpler way to do so?

Comment: If you're coding in C# you could look at [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/) which allows solution wide refactoring

Comment: Well, Nuget was invented to simplify references management, but it can be quite a hassle to switch to nuget.

Comment: If the reference is a NuGet package, Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45898835/1014320).